# Better way of merging two tree views into a single

Tags: gui-design, hierarchy, tree, categorization

I am working on a UI design which has two tree view components to show data hierarchy.

Each tree shows same data but has two different functionalities. I felt showing them in such a way will confuse the user.

Here I have attached an example image. Both trees are in same screen under user admin functionality.

[image]

- **Tree A:** It is used to select the list of categories & movies the user is allowed to watch.
- **Tree B:** This is a subset of Tree A. It will select the default/favorite movie for the user from the items selected in Tree A.

I want to keep it in a single tree and achieve both functionalities.

***Can some one help me find a better user experience for this?***

**Note:** There is sub categories also like Action, Comedy etc under each language.

Comment: Hi Murali. Can you amend your images so they don't have the text embedded within the image? You should use images as illustrations, and include the text as actual text in the question so that it is searchable and editible.

Comment: @JonW updated my question.

Comment: What is the purpose of selecting a default/favourite movie? Can I select more than one?

Comment: @MattObee, they can select more than one. Sometimes they select whole category or sub category like Comedy, Action. In Home page we show only favorites for easy navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the [question above](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/better-way-of-merging-two-tree-views-into-a-single/31215#comment45354_31215), in your list you could have a the paper icon change to an empty star when you tick the check box.  Then if they hover over the empty star it changes to a gold star and if they click it then the gold star will stay (the same way as you favourite something in Gmail). If you star English it would star all those below.

- [...] [image] Movies

  - [✓] [image] English

    - [✓] [image]  Lord of the Rings
    - [✓] [image] Gladiator
  - [...] [image] Hindi

    - [...] [image] Devdas
    - [...] [image] Mohabbatein

Obviously Gmail does the checkboxes and gold stars better than me:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You're on the wrong path, here.

The problem is that you try to show the *attributes* in different trees.

The *tree* should contain the *content*.
The attributes should be displayed *as attributes* to each node.

This can be done in various ways depending on the importance of attribute.

**As a column:**

[image]

...or:
- As a popup dialog
- By showing the attributes directly in the context menu
- Sliding into a new screen (mobile devices)

Comment: I also have sub category like Action, Comedy, Thriller. There will be atleast 5 levels. In that scenario Default column will be moving away from screen. I am thinking of having symbol like * next to the check box. Not sure how those things will be work with Tree component like http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-select.html

Comment: As the answer states you could try doing it with a right-click popup on the main tree - perhaps modifying the label to indicate that it is default

Comment: @icc97, if i do right click and select 'Favorite' option from context menu, how the user will feel its marked as favorite? Do we highlight those nodes in different color? Also it has more levels like Action, Comedy etc. In that case if i mark Action as favorite, i should highlight all children too.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it is not an easy task you got.

> One does not simply [tree graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_graph) movies.

### The tree representation is problematic

- If you add more attributes or features to a movie, you might need to be able to open up the items to edit them. You could consider how to do that later. But if you have to, the *open* action will be confused with the *expand* action.
- The same movie could be found in different nodes. Even more so if you add subcategories like Genre.

### Tag and search

Spontaneously, I would suggest a tag and search system instead.

On IMDB, [Gladiator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172495/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) **does not belong to** Drama, as much as it ***has*** Drama. Languages, Director and other attributes could also be categorized with tags.

Every link here would be a potential tree branch:

[image: slightly modified image 1]

A search box can find the end nodes. On StackExchange, you can also find end nodes by browsing tags.

Instead of drilling down a tree, tags could be searched and display all of the item with certain tags:

[image: slightly modified image 2]

Finally, you will have to handle setting attributes, considering that a movie can appear in different categories or subtrees at once. If a user may see English movies, but not Dramas, will the user be allowed to see Gladiator?

Comment: Only for example purpose i simulated my problem with Movies and Categories. However my actual data is pure hierarchical structure. One node cant be shared under two parent. I am dealing with Organization Hierarchy in real application

Comment: I admit that never really understood the user story.

Answer (score 1):

What about using one tree with the nodes having checkboxes to specify attributes:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCjflk.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The '[ ]' represent checkboxes.  You could have any number of attributes or states on a row.  Use of typography and colors could help distinguish between the main hierarchy and node attributes.